# Joining in python with quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I can join list entries by doing `value = ", ".join(str(val) for val in result)` so that the result is `a, b, c` etc.

How can I also add quotes to it in order to get `'a', 'b', 'c'`?

Comment: Or `", ".join(str(val).join("''") for val in result)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use string interpolation inside the join call:

```
value = ", ".join("'{}'".format(val) for val in result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uglier than the (now) top answer, but should also yield a valid output:

```
value = "'" + "', '".join(str(val) for val in result) + "'"
```